# Read multiple php files and replace HTML div with dynamic PHP code

Tags: php, html

I have multiple index.php files in different directories. I've created a script which goes through all of them (around 1000). What I need to do is to replace specific div (by it's class) with php code. The most important thing here is that source code remains unchanged (ON UNCHANGED PARTS).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the script that you are referring to.

Comment: removed unnecessary references

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.